# Analyzing txt file then exporting to excel

Tags: excel, nlp, data-analysis

I'm totally new to coding. Before attempting to solve this problem, it would be great to know which language could do this easily.

I have a large .txt file with data which looks like:

---- title: 1 ---- 
good
great
excellent
---- title: 2 ----
good
great
---- title: 3 ----
good
excellent
---- title: 4 ----
...

This goes on for about 2 million lines. My question is, can this be separated by title and exported to an excel file? such as each title being the header of a column? If so, can only the titles with "excellent" underneath it be exported?

Thanks very much for any help!

EDIT:

Firstly, thanks for the suggestions. I have tried over the weekend to get this into CSV format to no avail. It seems like the layout of the original .txt isn't readily able to 'drop-in' to CSV.

To shed more light on what I'm trying to extract data from, the .txt content resembles this format:

[sample text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnvli.png)

When I attempt VBA, I only get as far as displaying the content after "{" to "}" in rows, but fail when trying to create
"-------- title: X date: X --------"
row to separate and label this content (e.g. [hopeful excel outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2seP.png)). Is it even possible to use VBA to do this and only extract titles and dates if "report executed" is present? I'm open to other learning other methods of doing this, as it would be useful in some other research I'm doing.

Comment: You want to convert the text file to CSV (comma separated values), which Excel can read, but is not technically an "Excel file". This is easily accomplished in just about any programming language.

Comment: Keep in mind that the maximum number of columns in an Excel worksheet is  16,384.

Comment: Ok great, thanks! Will give this a try and report back.

Comment: Rather than using another language to get this into Excel, you can use Excel VBA (inside of Excel) to accomplish this.  It is simple to open and read a text file line-by-line then implement your logic.  Here is a good starting point: https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/read-data-from-text-file.html

Comment: Awesome, thanks! The link's step-by-step is extremely useful. Will report back with results.

Comment: Added an update to the original post, any suggestions are appreciated and welcome. Thanks.